# Re-using the DOM nodes leads to huge cumulative layout shifts (CLS)

Tags: reactjs, list, key, cls

[image]

Here's a list whose refreshing takes >500ms (normally, there would be a server request).

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-haze-6ku1v?file=/src/App.js:1268-1275

**Problem**:

On the one hand, **re-using the DOM nodes** by assigning straightforward keys to the items (the natural thing to do with ReactJS) quickly leads us to a **huge CLS** after a few reloads.

On the other hand, **re-creating the DOM nodes** gives us **performance overhead**, apart from the fact that preserving good UX now requires caching the data for the items.

**Question**:

Is there a solution which would solve both the CLS and the performance overhead?